# CDI Event<T> injection in class via producer method

Tags: java, cdi

Say I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
   @Inject
   private Event<MyEvent> myEvent;

   ...

   // Invoked by subclasses.
   protected void notifyListeners() {
      myEvent.fire(...);
   }
}
```

and a series of class which extends this abstract class:

```
public class MyOneClass extends MyAbstractClass { ... }

public class MyTwoClass extends MyAbstractClass { ... }
```

Then a producer method:

```
@Produces
MyAbstractClass getMyAbstractClass() {
   if (...) {
      return new MyOneClass();
   }

   return new MyTwoClass();
}
```

Will CDI inject injectable fields?

Comment: Small question: Did you try?

Comment: @Kukeltje Good question. Actually no, I'm still at the theoretical phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you instanciate MyOneClass or MyTwoClass in the producer using **new**.
Doing so, your instances will not be seen as managed beans by CDI, hence no injection will occur in them.

The correct way would be :

```
@Produces
MyAbstractClass getMyAbstractClass(MyOneClass class1, MyTwoClass class2) {
   if (...) {
      return class1;
   }
   return class2;
}
```

CDI will inject both (managed) beans upon calling the producer, and return the one you need.

Please note that you may also consider using qualifier to inject the appropriate bean instead of doing this (not always possible though).

Edit :
there is a documented exemple of this on the official site :https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html#gmglj

Edit2 : removed the @New anotations (see Siliarus's comment)

Comment: This sounds good to me! I had read about the New annotation, but totally forgot about it. This can work when the constructor of the New annotated parameter doesn't require non-managed arguments. I think for this latter case we could use an InjectionTarget passing the non-managed object (the manually created extension of MyAbstractClass) and a CreationalContext. CDI should perform the injections.

Comment: @LppEdd Hold right there, this is **not** the right way to go! `@New` has been deprecated for what is ages now. So unless you are running CDI 1.0, you don't want to use `@New`. Instead, those beans are dependent scope, so you can simply inject them into producer without any additional annotation.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove the @New anotations